# PHP5 COM(), DOTNET(): how to start?

Tags: .net, windows, com, php

Where I'm stuck is the right parameter syntax to instantiate an object using PHP's `com()` and `dotnet()` classes to load .net assemblies, windows system applications and components beyond the usual MS Office apps.  If successfully created, working with the objects isn't an issue here.

Can anyone explain what each part of each parameter means for both classes, and how I can find out the proper calling syntax for any application, component or assembly?  What exactly can or can't PHP load, and if it can, how?  How do I go about finding out which system components and classes are visible and can be made available through com() and dotnet()?  For calling assemblies, Im I incorrect in assuming anything listed in /windows/assembly/gacxx folders can be used here?

I'm trying to dig deeper into connecting to or using Windows system applications, components and assemblies.  For example, using 'System.Windows.Forms' assembly.  After reviewing [PHP's manual on the topic](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.com.php) including code examples, it's not getting any clearer for me.  By PHP's errors, I'm failing to get the syntax right, failing to find the specified files, or otherwise just failing completely without explanation.  No related events are showing in Event Viewer to hint at application crashing or denied access.

I have .net 4 framework installed.  These are my current PHP settings...

compiled: --enable-com-dotnet

[com_dotnet]

- COM support => enabled

  DCOM support => disabled

  .Net support => enabled

Directive => Local Value => Master Value

- com.allow_dcom => 0 => 0

  com.autoregister_casesensitive => no value => no value

  com.autoregister_typelib => 1 => 1

  com.autoregister_verbose => 1 => 1

  com.code_page => no value => no value

  com.typelib_file => no value => no value

I've managed to get just three cases working so far.  All other cases fail, including attempting to use other mscorlib classes...

```
<?php

$scripting = new COM("MSScriptControl.ScriptControl");
$scriping_host = new COM("WScript.Shell');
$stack = new DOTNET("mscorlib", "System.Collections.Stack");

?>
```

I see 'System.Windows.Forms' just sitting there in the /windows/assembly folder taunting me.  `$forms = new DOTNET('System.Windows.Forms', 'Form');` fails, even if the full assembly string is used.  Am I looking in the wrong place?  Should I instead approach this from within .net and create my own assembly to allow me to dynamically call others from PHP?

Note: Using the win32api PHP extension instead is right out as it's a dead project, and I'm hoping to step away from being dependent on others' pet project extensions.

**Edit:** COM issue mostly solved.  Within the registry, I was able to find a list of com supported software and system components and create several com objects using their clsid's.  Still unsure exactly how to create DOTNET objects though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$forms = new DOTNET('System.Windows.Forms', 'System.Windows.Forms.Form');
```

I notice that the examples from the manual use fully-qualified class names.

Comment: No luck: "The system cannot find the file specified"

Comment: Are you able to create and run a simple Windows Forms application on the server system? Install [Visual Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express) if necessary to test this. The next most likely answer would be that .NET isn't installed correctly.

Comment: @John Just now installed vb express 2010 to try this building a console test app.  Within vb, I was able to reference System.Windows.Forms via .Net and use classes and methods from that library to build a form.  The test app compiled, installed and executed successfully.  Tried again with PHP, still no luck.  I then reinstalled .Net.  Then tried again with PHP, still no luck.

Comment: @bob: just tried it myself (in a web service) and got an internal server error.

Comment: @John OK, although I just got it working, I'm stumped on what caused the problem. `$form = new DOTNET('System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=<my_assembly_token>', 'System.Windows.Forms.Form');` works, and `$form->Show();`  pops up a form. All I can guess is either the original assembly string I was using had a typo, I wasn't using the full assembly string with the fully-qualified class name before, or reinstalling .net repaired the issue. At any rate, now I understand it, and now I'm off.

Comment: Also, your suggestion to install visual studio express helps a lot as it gives me a platform to quickly look up and test related classes and methods with their descriptions.

Comment: @bob: I'm thinking that you had more than one version of System.Windows.Forms installed, and needed to specify which.

Answer (score 0):

Using the COM and DOTNET classes is a nightmare. There are **so many caveats that do not appear in the manuals**. Simply put, you cannot get a regular .Net binary and expect to consume it from PHP (without NetPHP).

Using COM you can instantiate any COM component in the system.

Using DOTNET you can only target .NET assemblies that have been compiled for the .NET 3.5 or below.

Class constructors cannot have parameters, and everything needs to be decorated as COM Visible.

This basically means that you need to make your custom libraries for everything... unusable.

There is a ver convenient wrapper, the [PhpNet][1] library, that makes it a breeze to consume .Net from PHP and solves all these problems:

- Use any .Net binaries (even without COM Visibility)
- Iterate over .Net collections directly from PHP
- Access native enums and static methods
- Use class constructors with parameters
- Debug .Net and PHP code at the same time as if it was a single application.
- Work with libraries compiled for any version of the .Net framework (including 4.0 and above)

This is what I am talking about:

```
$manager = new \NetPhp\Core\NetManager();
$manager->RegisterAssembly('mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089', 'mscorlib');
$manager->RegisterClass('mscorlib', 'System.IO.File', 'File');
$manager->RegisterClass('mscorlib', 'System.IO.FileOptions', 'FileOptions');
$file = $manager->Create('mscorlib', 'File');
$fileoptions = $manager->Create('mscorlib', 'System.IO.FileOptions')->Enum('Encrypted');

$file->Create("C:\\www\\prueba.tres", 2048, $fileoptions);
```

Answer (score -1):

The PHP manual states that [COM](http://php.net/manual/en/class.com.php) and [DOTNET](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dotnet.php) are classes not functions.

You ask how to use these classes. The manual page for each contains detailed descriptions of the constructor arguments along with examples and a fair amount of associated user-contributed documentation.

Do the manual pages not provide what you need?

Comment: Woops, corrected.  No, the manual pages aren't helping a whole lot.  By the description of proper dotnet() syntax, `$forms = new DOTNET('System.Windows.Forms', 'Form');` should work, even if adding the full 'version' and 'publickeytoken' assembly string.  This is what's confusing me.